# jQuery what is the best way to submit meta data of dynamically created elements?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Basically I am creating a number of rectangles using jQuery and adding these to the DOM e.g.

```
var divElement = jQuery('<div/>').attr({
'class': 'ui-widget-content resizable'
});
```

I am then allowing the user to fill out input fields for the selected rectangle e.g. name, width, height.  This data is currently being added to each element via .data method.

Once the user has created all their elements along with their associated meta data, I would like them to submit the page so I can do some server side scripting in PHP.

Just wondering what the best way is to submit this data - as I understand it, I could dynamically create form elements or use the jQuery.post method.

Please can anyone advise on the best method (perhaps a different one altogether) and any tips on how to set this up e.g. using [] brackets in the name of each element to create arrays etc..

Answer (score 1):

A good way will be to construct an object, or array, and fill it with all the data you wish to save. and then send it to your server using $.post() for storage.

```
var data = new Array;
data['height'] = 100;
data['width'] = 200;
$.post('save.php', data, function(result){
    // test if successful and carry on
});
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/